# How would i Print An Array like array([2]=>4,[6]=>8,[5]=>7)

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have been given array like

```
array(2,4,5,6,7,8).
```

Now I was asked to do some array operation which will give me output as

```
array([2]=>4,[6]=>8,[5]=>7)
```

Comment: Provide more information. This makes very less sense.

Comment: Have you done any research before posting this here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  <?php

$array=array("2"=>4,"6"=>8,"5"=>7);

$data=array_keys($array);
$data1=array_values($array);
$result = array_merge($data, $data1);
sort($result);
print_r($result);

?>
```

Output:`Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 [3] => 6 [4] => 7 [5] => 8 )`